# Windows Universal App Oracle Database Connection

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, windows-runtime, universal

i want to create a Windows Universal App for my Raspberry Pi with Windows 10. I need a access to a Oracle database.

So i add a Oracle DataAccess reference to my project.

When i create a Oracle Command like this

```
OracleCommand OraComm = OraConn.CreateCommand();
```

this error occurs:

> CS0012  C# The type '' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Now i add a System.Data reference to my project again.

After that, this error occurs on the same command.

> CS7069  C# Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Is it possible to get a database access with windows universal app?
Why does this error occurs?

Comment: I would recommend using [SQLite](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e)

Comment: I second the comment above. AFAIK the only DB you can use with UWA is SQLite. Attempting to manually add .NET references will not work with WinRT/UWA either- it's not the same framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a WCF service which in turn calls the Oracle database using the the code above.

UI <-> WCF <-> Database

Comment: There is the issue. Now the database is inhouse, The App/UI is running inhouse. I don't want to add WCF to a web server or even put the WCF in external server.  Now what do I do?  If it is external, why would internal data received in internal device go external to WCF?  Why should I cater/pay to that bandwidth?  Completely unacceptable architecture!!!  We know several organizations not willing to go this way.  Until UWA is not able to connect directly to my DB (Any DB at our choice, not just SqlLite), its only going to be Java development not .NET.

Comment: @Venkat - For what it's worth, you can use mysql directly without the wcf service.

Comment: Are you telling UWA can connect to MySQL directly without WCF service? Please clarify.

Comment: Starting Win10 build 17763 you should be able to directly connect to your database from your Universal Store App.  Welcome to Windows Store!!!